# Programming Arduino from Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, arduino

I have a custom PCB with an ATmega328 dip microcontroller. I program it with the Arduino IDE, through the FTDI port, which works fine.

I want it to program it through my own custom GUI. For that I created a process to run a Linux command to program the microcontroller. The command look like this, [detailed link](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc)
`{path_to_arduino}/arduino --board arduino:avr:pro --port /dev/tty_USB0 --upload {path_to_sketch}/test.ino`

Earlier, it worked great, with a small-size hex file. Now the code is big and the compilation output from the Arduino IDE for `test.ino` is (fine).

`Sketch uses 29,790 bytes (96%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30,720 bytes.
Global variables use 924 bytes (45%) of dynamic memory`

From the terminal, the compilation output for `test.ino` is different:

`Sketch uses 33,182 bytes (108%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30,720 bytes.
Global variables use 972 bytes (47%) of dynamic memory,`

I have checked, I selected the same file in the Arduino IDE and in the terminal. Can someone help me and tell me why there is a difference in sketch sizes?

Comment: This really looks like a different optimization level. Weird, because the platform.txt file should be the same. Do you have two installations of arduino? Check that you are calling exactly the same executable... Moreover try to go into the arduino installation dir, hardware, arduino, maybe avr and look for the file platform.txt. Inside you will find the compiler flags, you should see a -Os (or -O0, 1, 2 or 3). Try changing all these flags (try with -Os, -O0, -O1, -O2, -O3) and compare again, then report back

Comment: you are absolutely right. Thank for pointing me in right direction.
Silly mistake, I was using Arduino1.6.11 IDE, but in the terminal I was using executable from old installation Arduino 1.6.9. The optimizations are different for different versions.

Comment: now I use correct executable and following command to get correct results. `{path_to_arduino}/arduino --board arduino:avr:pro:cpu=8MHzatmega328 --port /dev/tty_USB0 --upload {path_to_sketch}/test.ino`

Comment: Glad this was helpful :) Happy coding ;)